# angular ui bootstrap - How to access modal scope without creating controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for the `$modal` service say

> The scope associated with modal's content is augmented with 2 methods:
>
> -`$close(result)`
>
> -`$dismiss(reason)`
>
> Those methods make it easy to close a modal window without a need to create a dedicated controller.

I'm wondering how to access this scope without creating a dedicated controller.

Comment: You would access it in the template

Comment: I have tried `<button ng-click="$close()">OK</button>` but clicking this button doesn't close the modal.

Comment: Where? These would only be available in the modal template.

Comment: Yes, this is in the modal template.

Comment: Hmm, I mustn't have cleared my cache because this is now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.openModal=function(){
  $scope.modalInstance=$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
    scope:$scope
  });
}

$scope.close=function(){
  $scope.modalInstance.dismiss();
};
```

now you can use `ng-click="close()"` in your temnplate file.

Answer (score 0):

ı used this code.

```
module.service('ModalService', function ($modal) {
    var modalOptions = {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        modalFade: true,
        templateUrl: null
    };

    this.show = function (customModalDefaults) {
        var tempModalOptions = {};
        angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalDefaults);

        if (!tempModalOptions.controller) {
            tempModalOptions.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                    $modalInstance.close(result);
                };
                $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            };
        }

        return $modal.open(tempModalOptions).result;
    };
});
```

call:

```
                    var modalOptions = {
                        backdrop: true,
                        modal: true,
                        size: scope.options.size || 'lg',
                        templateUrl: '/Apps/inekle/views/common/include_modal.html?v=1',
                        controller: [
                            "$scope", "$modalInstance", function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                                $scope.model = {
                                    template: scope.options.template,
                                    title: scope.options.title
                                };

                                $scope.close = function () {
                                    $modalInstance.dismiss('close');
                                };
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    ModalService.show(this.options).then(function (model) {},function (error) { });
```